# Minimize $\max\{xy, 1-x-y+xy, x+y-2xy\}$ over $0\leq x \leq y \leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

Find the minimum possible value of the largest of $xy$, $1-x-y+xy$, and $x+y-2xy$ if $0\leq x \leq y \leq 1$.

In other words, solve the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{0\le x \le y \le 1} \max\Big\{xy,\,\, 1 - x - y + xy, \,\, x + y - 2xy\Big\}.$$

---

I know that $1-x-y+xy=(x-1)(y-1)$, but I'm not sure what to do next. I also considered cases for $x$ and $y$, but it also didn't work. If anyone could give any hints, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: This question has been asked several times before. See [Approach0's result](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cmax%5C%7Bxy%2C%201-x-y%2Bxy%2C%20x%2By-2xy%5C%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Oh ok, thanks!!

Comment: It is not the same question and the answer is different too.

Comment: @Magician: in case you haven't solved your problem yet, here is a systematic approach: introduce an additional variable $t$ and write your problem as $\min t$ s.t. $xy \le t$, $1 - x - y - xy \le t$, $x+y-2xy \le t$ and $0 \le x \le y \le 1$. Then apply the method of Lagrange multipliers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Examples